# Is there any Shaders Directory?

Tags: web, shaders

There are many tutorials to learn GLSL, Cg, HLSL... with classical samples as bump mapping, toon-shading...

But is there a shaders directory?

- a website where i can share my shaders
- search shader by name, description and implementation

Comment: Maybe with WebGL there will be

Comment: Someone should get on this. :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe [NVIDIA Shader library](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/shaderlibrary/webpages/shader_library.html) can help you, but it's not large shader library.

Answer (score 2):

While not a website, the ShaderX series of books (7 at present) is a good reference about common shader effects.

Some are available for free download at http://tog.acm.org/resources/shaderx/

Answer (score 2):

Yup; there's definitely not enough of these! In addition to the above, the samples that come with [RenderMonkey](http://developer.amd.com/gpu/rendermonkey/Pages/default.aspx) have definitely been helpful for me.

Answer (score 0):

There are are few online locations that allow you to visualize on the fly the shader you're typing ; they often based on WebGL.
One of them is called the "Shader Toy" (http://www.iquilezles.org/apps/shadertoy/).
An other one is called the "GLSL Sandbox" (http://glsl.heroku.com/), and it seems that you can save and share your creations there (I am not 100% sure however).

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Anko Thanks for pointing that out. I added more context to my answer.