# 2d Pixel Shader literature, algorithms, etc. for Pixel Bender for flash

Tags: flash, shaders

I am looking for some literature about pixel shaders algorithms or how would you call it.
It's for 2d top down space shooter kind of game.

I was thinking effects like halos, slow time, trails, fast speed feeling..

I'm not looking for a guide how to code in Pixel Bender but for something that will teach me how to move pixels around to get expected effect.

Comment: -1 because I can't figure out what you're asking. You want "literate, algorithms, etc." for Pixel Bender but not something about coding Pixel Bender, which is how you'd achieve those effects?

Comment: If you don't know what I'm asking then please don't answer. I'm looking for literature for making shaders. I mentioned Pixel Bender to make it clear I do not use openGL, direct3d or any other similar soft. Just because one can write code doesn't mean he know how to write game. Shaders are mostly about math and simple ifs. I can do ifs, I'm looking for math.

Comment: I don't know what you're asking because you expressed yourself poorly, not because I'm unfamiliar with the technology involved. What are you actually looking for? Examples of shader programs written for Pixel Bender?

Comment: Algorithms or generally literature explaining me what to do with pixels to get effect I need such as halo around objects, slowmotion feeling, etc. Everything I found until now was meant for 3d stuff with openGl or something. Nothing for 2d.

Comment: This question is too vague; either the correct answer is the Pixel Bender site, or http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1673/is-there-any-shaders-directory, or http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/2419/cool-examples-of-procedural-pixel-shader-effects, or ask a specific question ("I have X in Flash, how can I add a halo?")

Comment: I don't think it is too vague. Answer might as well be: buy this book, chapter x, there you can find stuff applicable to 2d shaders too. Or link or whatever. I'm not looking for concrete solution but rather for general principles.

Comment: @Antriel, but *specific* questions are much better than general discussion style topics.  You'll have much better luck with "how do I achieve effect-I-want X" than "I want to learn more about topic Y".  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: I could provide you with the source of any of the demos here: http://ryanspeets.com/uncategorized/the-speets-is-not-dead/

Comment: Specific questions might be better, but having tens of questions with basically equal content won't be exactly better right? I don't know what effects I want, I want to learn principles behind these effects so I can mess up with it and try to make my own.

Comment: The principles are the *ifs* you talked about. There is no generic math or magic solution to create all the effects you want. I think you would be better off by writing one shader, ask specific questions and then broaden your knowledge from there. On a side note: Pixelbender is frustratingly limited. You can't even do loops (when used in flash)

Comment: The general principles are covered in the Pixel Bender documentation, which you said you don't want. What you do want is a dozen specific things. In that case, it should be split into a dozen questions.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to go for the basics with examples, then I guess this is where I would start:

- [Texturing and Modeling: A Procedural Approach](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1558608486)

Also there is a ton of other books considering shaders (with examples):

- [Graphics Shaders: Theory and Practice](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1568813341)
- [Shaders for Game Programmers and Artists](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1592000924)
- [Programming Vertex & Pixel Shaders](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1584503491)
- ShaderX series
- GPU Gems series

You could also take a look at: [Modern Shader Book?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/6236/modern-shader-book)